# IO error: not a gzipped file in python

Tags: python

I'm programming a RPG game, so I have the function `load_map`, with an XML map, I have to decode and decompress the layer. This is the code:

```
# Decodifica una cadena en base64 y luego la descomprime.
def decode(cadena):
    # Decodificar.
    cadena = base64.decodestring(cadena)

    # Descomprimir.
    copmressed_stream = StringIO.StringIO(cadena)
    gzipper = gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=copmressed_stream)
    cadena = gzipper.read()

    # Convertir.
    salida = []
    for idx in xrange(0, len(cadena), 4):
        val = ord(str(cadena[idx])) | (ord(str(cadena[idx + 1])) << 8) | \
        (ord(str(cadena[idx + 2])) << 16) | (ord(str(cadena[idx + 3])) << 24)
        salida.append(val)

    return salida
```

The error is in `cadena=gzipper.read()`. Why am I getting this error, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Python appears to think it isn't a gzip file. Are you sure it is? Try, for example, decompressing it with the command-line `gzip` command. Does it complain?

Comment: sorry but i don't understand very well this part of the code,i got this part of a page, can you show me how you modify this code?

Comment: I'm not sure it's so much a problem with the *code* as it is the data coming in. The code you have for reading a gzip file looks right.

Comment: now i have this error: attribute error: 'module' object has no attribute 'Gzipfile'

Comment: That's because the `F` in `GzipFile` is supposed to be uppercase, as it is in your question. As I said before, you need to make sure the data that's coming in really is valid gzip data; you can't even begin to check the code if you don't know that it's really a gzip that's coming in.

Comment: sorry, i didn't saw the F, i removed this accidentally, now i have the  same error as before xD, gzipper is a gzip file, i don't know what's the mistake here, i took this method from http://razonartificial.com/2010/06/engine-vii-la-clase-mapa-i/, i'll continue trying to resolve it

Answer (score -1):

add exception catch such as try...except... will be good. you can make sure your test file-type is gzip by shell command as icktoofay. Certianly , command 'file test.gzip' will  work.

Comment: Sure, you can catch the exception reading the gzip file will throw with a `try`-`catch`, but what would you do once you've caught it? Simply not decompress it? Unless it was already decompressed (in which case, that's the problem and you should avoid trying to decompress it lest you come across a file that just happens to be a valid gzip file as well), that won't solve anything. The only sensible thing to do is to signal an error, which is what not handling the exception already does.

Comment: i resolved this, sorry, i have the xml archive with compression zlib, that was the problem, sorry by that stupid question xD

Comment: Maybe.You can catch your customized exception if you like, then deal with it. sometime it's not enough time reading the docs for new interfaces, check the exception oneself is not unnecessary, I think.